# Windows Firewall seems useless out of the box - How to properly configure?

Tags: windows-11, windows-firewall

I am running a fresh new Windows 11 installation. To my understanding, to make it secure you would need the firewall, by default, to block external connections and to prevent malware from reaching externally and sending/downloading data.

So, the first thing I do is install Google Chrome, run it, and boom: it's completely connecting to the web without any blocks from the firewall by default. Steam: exactly the same, no blocks. I presume this will happen with any software by default.

I might be missing something so please correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems it is as good as nothing at default configurations. **My question is:** how to configure the Windows firewall so that there is a hard block on every single process to connect externally unless it is whitelisted?

Comment: The firewall is by default configured to block incoming connections not outgoing. And those programs that open a server socket usually add automatically a allow firewall rule during the installation process.

Comment: If you only define "useful" as its ability to block digitally signed, Defender-checked, UAC-passed installed applications to connect out, then yes, it is useless. Others define the utility of a firewall in terms of blocking *incoming* connections ...

Answer (score 2):

The default configuration of the Windows Firewall only blocks incoming traffic by default.

To block outgoing traffic as well, just change the default setting from `Allow (default)` to `Block`. Make sure to apply it to all the network profiles (Domain, Private, Public) you need it to work on. Be aware that you have to add a rule for each program/port/IP you want to allow access to the network (except for the default allow-rules that are already enabled)!

[image]

If the default makes sense or not is debatable, but that's the compromise between security and user-friendliness Microsoft decided on: access to the network is unrestricted (e.g. browsing the web or client applications in general) and access by the network is restricted (e.g.RPD or server applications in general). So in a way, your initial assumption "to prevent malware from reaching externally and sending/downloading data" (if by reaching externally you mean accessing the network) is not correct, therefore it's not useless.

Comment: For a completely fresh Windows install the default makes complete sense. The only applications that exist have already been granted your trust by agreeing to install Windows. If you haven't even entered personal information then the risk of the first-party Windows applications leaking something private is extremely low too. As soon as you start customizing your install and adding third party software it is your responsibility to adjust firewall policies to your preferences.

Comment: In general, I agree, however, I also agree with sigmaxf, so I leave it at it is what it is both have a valid point.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine the average user who cracks open their fresh Windows. They log in, open Edge, and they get a warning that the firewall blocked it. They have to approve the connection. That gets them to the Bing homepage.

Then they open a new tab to get to Steam. That's blocked too, and they need to approve the connection. That's just to open the tab. Then they connect to Steam and download the client.

They download the Steam installer, but they need to approve the connection to download the rest of the installer.

Then, after they install the client, they need to approve the connection to the Steam store (that's a different binary from the installer).

And so on, and so on, for every binary. By the way, Windows Firewall used to do this years ago. In response, people used to turn off the firewall entirely.

Implementing a network control for local binaries is controlling the wrong end of the stick. Control the binary environment, instead.

**Firewalls focus on network-level threats, and that's primarily incoming connections.**

If you want to add network-level protections against malware, **then Windows Firewall still isn't your best bet**. You would want to look at an IPS or something that can analyse the traffic for anomalies and then make a decision. Windows Firewall is too simple for that level of analysis.